# Excel - VLOOKUP return based on partial string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to get VLOOKUP to return a value based on a partial string. So I want to say: look up this string, look in the list and if you find a partial string matching it, return the date next to it. But not having much luck. In my example, B2 should show: April 9th as the first bit of the string in D2 matches.

[image]

Comment: Apply left() to A2 for the vlookup so it only looks for the characters expected in col D.

Comment: I still get NA: =VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2),$D$2:$E$4,2,0)

Comment: =VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,7),D:E,2,0) you should specify number of characters in left

Comment: @RichStevens I did say “expected characters”...

Comment: @SolarMike I don't know the amount, could be different. I need to look up the piece that I do know and match it. Sorry if not so clear.

Comment: @PawelCzyz still gives me NA

Comment: @RichStevens I was just about to post how to use find() to get the position of the second space... but done by two people for you - I suggest you give them credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=VLOOKUP(MID(A2,1,FIND(" ",A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1)-1),$D$2:$E$4,2,FALSE)
```

**Results:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this one... Will help you

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A3,FIND(" ",A3,FIND(" ",A3)+1)-1),$D$3:$E$5,2,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do the other way around and use combination of INDEX and MATCH (with wildcard match) - look at the picture:

=INDEX($D$1:$E$4,MATCH(D2&"*",$A$2:$A$4,0)+1,2)

[INDEX MATCH example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCtdg.png)

Advantage is of this is that you do not assume a given pattern of your values. So it does not matter whether it is SPXL APR19 59P or SPXL APR19_____59P.

You can also use the asterisk on both sides "*"&[]&"*", so then you'll do an inside search.